# User Of local Databases to temporary store data For main Database in Case of Internet non Availability

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I Have Project of Nation wide Transport Company, i need to build a Ticketing System. It will be a web based asp application using Sql Server 2008 r2 Database. Main Database will b managed at Server. In Case Internet is not available, application will work with local system Database. When Internet available local db will update the changes to Main Server DB and also update itself from server Database. How can i do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. How can you do this from a technical perspective? Or how can you do this from an architectural perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the approach is to record the transaction statements that update the local db, and then replay them for the main db.